# Displaying multiple 2d raster layers on top of each other in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I have 4 raster layers of the same shape but different values for each cell that I want to overlay on top of each other. This should be with some vertical space between each, so you can see the bottom 3 layers partially with a full view of the 4th layer on top. I've tried converting my layers into 3d layers, and feature classes, etc. but no matter what when I look at the Base Heights tab, the middle section "Elevation from Features" is greyed out.

I'm currently using ArcGIS 10.3.1.